# creating elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Taking this code

```
<app-localstorage-document key="search" data="{{plAppLoader}}"> </app-localstorage-document>
```

The data property will always be updated when it changes, and saved to local storage, and looking in the console, the string representation of the object is shown with the keys and values, basically the whole structure.

Importing and creating this dynamically

```
var ALD = document.createElement('app-localstorage-document');
Polymer.dom(ALD).setAttribute('key', 'plAppLoader');
Polymer.dom(ALD).setAttribute('data', this.plAppLoader);
Polymer.dom(this.$.contentWrapper).appendChild(ALD);
```

It is updated on the on change but looking at the console, it shows

> "[object Object]"

Which makes me wonder, does it get saved like the first option, i.e, even though it shows "[object Object]" in the console log, I can still retrieve the original data as an object from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting objects to strings. Instead of `+`, use `,` in the console.

```
console.log(this.is, ': app-localstorage-document element has been created!');
```